# Describe all k-tuples (n1, n2,...,nk) of natural numbers, k = 1, 2,..., such that complete bipartite graph K(n1,n2,...,nk) is a planar graph.

Tags: graph-theory

I have tried this question by drawing different graphs and guessing but nothing general in is coming to be true for all complete bipartite graphs.

Question-
Describe all k-tuples $(n_1, n_2,...,n_k)$ of natural numbers, $k = 1, 2,...,$
such that complete bipartite graph $K(n_1,n_2,...,n_k)$ is a planar graph.

Comment: Do you know that every nonplanar graph contains either the complete graph on $5$ vertices $K_5$ or the complete bipartite graph on $6$ vertices $K_{3,3}$?

Comment: @M.Nestor No, is it necessarily true? And if it is true how do we say about k>2.

Comment: @M.Nestor Contains a *subdivision* of either $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$, so it's not as straightforward as you make it sound.

Comment: What is a complete bipartite graph $K(n_1,...,n_k)$? Do yo mean complete multipartite graph?

Comment: Here is a link about complete multipartite graph being planar :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256204/multipartite-graphs-which-are-not-planar